# file sent using form data api to express api is showing undefined in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a simple express api to upload file.I have used formData api.
But shows undefined to my image in console but image name is logged in console .What I have done wrong and how I can fix this issue. I have tried but nothing happen.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my frontend code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
const Login=()=>{
    const[image,setImage]=useState();
    const [imageName,setImageName]=useState("")
const send=async(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const formData=new FormData();
formData.append('file',image);
formData.append('name',imageName)
    try {
        const res=await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/post',formData)
        console.log(res.data)
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }

}
const handleImage=(e)=>{
let image=e.target.files[0]
console.log(image)
setImageName(image.name);
setImage(image)
}
    return(
        <>
        <form method ="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
       <div className="w-1/2 mx-auto h-full overflow-hidden my-4">
      <div className="mx-4 py-8 items-center text-center">
        <div className="flex items-center py-2 space-x-2 cursor-pointer">
           <h2>Login With Google</h2>
        </div>
       <div className="flex items-center py-2 space-x-2 cursor-pointer">
         <h2>Login With Facebook</h2>
         <input type="file" name="file" onChange={handleImage}/>
        </div>
      </div>
       </div>
        <input  type="submit" onClick={send} value="send "></input>
       </form>
        </>
    )
}
export default Login
```

backend code

```
const  express=require('express');
const cors=require('cors');
const app =express( );  
const fs=require('fs');
const fileUpload=require('express-fileupload');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send("working")
})
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(fileUpload())
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
const dir='upload';
if (fs.existsSync(dir)) {
    console.log(`already exist directory ${dir}`);
}
else{
    fs.mkdirSync(dir)
}
app.post('/post',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.name)
    console.log(req.body.file)
})
const PORT=process.env.PORT||8000
app.listen(PORT,()=>{
console.log(`server is listening in port number ${PORT}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

kindly console **req.files** instead of **req.body.file** you will get the object in server

enjoy coding